# Const reference to R value

Tags: c++

In C++ it is valid to use take a `const` reference to a temporary:

```
const std::string& s = std::string("abc");
std::cout << s.length() << std::endl; // valid because string instance is still alive
```

But does this hold true if the temporary was created via a conversion from another type?

For example:

```
struct Foo
{ 
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << "Foo destructor?" << endl;
    }
};

struct Bar
{ 
    operator Foo()
    {
        return Foo();
    }

    ~Bar()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }
};

Foo getFoo()
{
    return Foo();
}

Bar getBar()
{
    return Bar();
}

int main()
{
    const Foo& f = getBar();
        /* is f valid here, or is it a dangling reference? */
    std::cout << "We're still in main!" << std::endl;
}
```

I note that Bar's destructor is called *before* `We're still in main` is output, which makes me think that `Foo& f` is a dangling reference.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter how the temporary was created. If you bind a `const X&` or an `X&&` to a local prvalue, the lifetime of the temporary gets extended to the lifetime of the reference.

Answer (score 2):

The function `getBar` creates an object of type `Bar` and immediately destroys returning a **copy** of it.

```
Bar getBar()
{
    return Bar();//the lifetime of Bar() is only on this line;
}
```

Edit:

For the question in the source code if `const Foo & f` is valid; yes it is because `getBar` returns an object copy. 
Also after checking the code i see that it first returns a copy of Bar and then casts it to `Foo`

Also i must mention the RVO (from the comments section) which is an optimization from the compiler. The lifetime of the object is still defined by it's scope `{}` however in this case the construction is done inside the function and the destruction is outside the function. This optimization will not work of you give a name to the variable like such:

```
Bar getBar()
{
    Bar tmp_value;
    return tmp_value;
}
```

Razvan.

Comment: I disagree. RVO is optimalization that removes unnecessary destruction+copy constructor, but for clarity this explanation is enough.

Plus, RVO is optional.

Comment: I like this answer more. The other failed to explain why the desctructor is called.